# Left and top values change while positioning a dialog in host window on multi monitor screens

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, multiple-monitors

I am setting a child dialog to an existing application window. I would like the dialog to appear on bottom right corner of host window.  Hence I am setting the top and left of the dialog with help of commented lines. The code works properly on primary screen of multimonitor system but does not work on secondary screen. The top and left values change by themselve to different number than what was assigned.
As a test, I manually hardcoded values to check if the values remain same and they do not. For left 495 changes to -2416 and dtop changes from 643 to 760. The resolution of screen is 1920 X 1080. I am not able to understand why this is happening and how to correctly set window so that window appears on bottom right corner of host window on a multidisplay screen.

```
 dialog.DataContext = opsViewModel;
        var window = Window.GetWindow(dialog);
        var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
        var childWindowHandle = wih.Handle;
        var returnHandle = NativeMethods.SetParent(childWindowHandle, parentWindowHandle);
        dialog.Show();
        // dialog.Left = docView.ClientRectangle.Right - dialog.Width;
        // dialog.Top = docView.ClientRectangle.Bottom - dialog.Height;
        dialog.Left = -495;
        dialog.Top = 643;
```

Comment: Is the second screen a high DPI screen and/or have a scaling factor different to the first screen?

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you for replying to my question. No, both displays are at 100% scaling with 1920X1080 resolution. And both display are exactly same from Dell and same model. The Dpivalue in registry (Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings\DELD059293M33820DWT_1F_07DD_08^5183DD075D9012E86C970 has a value of 1C053E45A5D) has a value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this
1) It adds secondary monitor's resolution width to the X coordinate of the dialog.
2) However deducting the resolution width as well does not help.
3) Hence eventually I avoided setting dialog.Left and dialog.Top values, but instead used Windows Native method.

```
       /// <summary>
    /// Changes the position and dimensions of the specified window. For a top-level window, the position and dimensions are relative to the upper-left corner of the screen. For a child window, they are relative to the upper-left corner of the parent window's client area. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The new position of the left side of the window. </param>
    /// <param name="y">The new position of the top of the window. </param>
    /// <param name="nWidth">The new width of the window. </param>
    /// <param name="nHeight">The new height of the window. </param>
    /// <param name="bRepaint">Indicates whether the window is to be repainted. If this parameter is TRUE, the window receives a message. If the parameter is FALSE, no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent window uncovered as a result of moving a child window.</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</returns>
    [DllImport(USER32, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```